# Jquery scrollTo prevent queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, scrollto

Ok simple question for scrollTo. I'm looking for a way to prevent the queuing of the scroll animations. I've tried to work in stop() but it doesn't seem to do the trick.. any Ideas? here's the code...

> ('#nav_hold li a').click(function(){
>
> $currLoc = $(this).attr('href');
>
> ```
> $newLoc = $currLoc.replace('#!','');
> ```
>
> $newLoc = "#"+$newLoc;
>
> $(window).scrollTo($newLoc, 1000);
> });

here's the site FYI http://www.dudnyk.com/files/connector/

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem, but I found the solution here http://usejquery.com/sites/contrast-rebellion

Just use the line 
`jQuery.scrollTo.window().queue([]).stop();` before any new scrollTo.

Comment: +1 for great solution. Afaik `$.scrollTo.window().stop(true);` should do the same thing. Works for my usage case anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

There is function [clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/). I think that should help.

Answer (score 1):

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) Is for removing the currently running animation, to also clear to queue use `.stop(true)`

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $(this).stop(true);
    $.scrollTo('#about', 1000); 
});
```

From jQuery Docs (linked above):

> If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the
>   later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element.
>   These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When
>   .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately.
>   If the clearQueue parameter is provided with a value of true, then the
>   rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ queue : false }
```

as the scrollTo option

but that's the default. doesn't the anchor click get you somewhere?

Comment: This queue refers to the x/y animation within a single scroll event. This has nothing to do with queued animated scroll events, and is therefore completely irrelevant. Please remove this answer or edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.scrollTo` on any element it is actually scrolling(with animation) the document until the scroll reaches to the specified element. So I believe we should stop the animation on document. Try this

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $(window).stop();
    $.scrollTo('#about', 1000); 
});
```